# Map Function of Python 2

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Hi I am running the following code

```
arr = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
for x in arr:
    print(arr[x-1])
```

my inputs are

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

I am expecting the output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

but it is showing

```
5 0 1 2 3 4
```

can anybody please explain why it is happening ?

Comment: use `for x in arr: print(x)` instead.

Comment: got my mistake thank you Thanks every one

Answer (score 2):

After this statement:

```
arr = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
```

Value of arr is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When you loop over `arr` and use `x-1` the first print statement becomes `arr[0-1]` which is in fact `arr[-1]` which is the last element.

```
for x in arr:
    print(arr[x-1])

# x = 0 => arr[0-1] => arr[-1] => 5
# x = 1 => arr[1-1] => arr[0]  => 0
# x = 2 => arr[2-1] => arr[1]  => 1
# x = 3 => arr[3-1] => arr[2]  => 2
# x = 4 => arr[4-1] => arr[3]  => 3
# x = 5 => arr[5-1] => arr[4]  => 4
```

If you just want to print the values:

```
for x in arr:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` goes from `0` to `5`. (Note that they are values, not indices.) `x - 1` thus starts with `-1`, then continues with `0` to `4`. `arr[-1]` is the last element of `arr` (negative indices count backwards from the end), and then you get the first 5 elements with `arr[0]...arr[4]`.

Basically, you really just wanted

```
for x in arr:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
test = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by a space")

arr = map(int,test.strip().split(' '))
for x in arr:
   print(x), #, prints on the same line in Python 2.7
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

You can test it out for yourself [here](https://www.repl.it/CTx5/1)

Other answers to this question will give output that is not on the same line:

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

Answer (score -1):

At first iteration, `x=0`.

The code then do `arr[x-1]` which is interpreted as `arr[0-1]` or `arr[-1]`. In python, negative list indices is interpreted as index from the back of the list, so `arr[-1]` is the same as `arr[len(arr)-1]`, which is `arr[4]`, i.e. the last element.